# Not able to remove Google App engine Service from the admin console

Tags: google-app-engine, console, google-apps

How to delete Google app engine services from admin console which was added through developer email login. After paid google hosting now I am not able to login with developer email account 
Its now only allow with the email account which I open for this domain email account. I set all the permission (Super Admin, Groups Admin, User Management Admin, Help Desk Admin, Services Admin) but still when I try to remove Google app engine service from admin console it give this error,  You do not have the permissions necessary to uninstall this application.

I also try to create one more user tried to remove Google app engine services  but still same error message not removing services.

**Please help me to remove all Google app engine services and after I will add again google app engine  services with this newly created email account for this domain.**

Comment: Did you perform the disable steps listed here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/applicationsettings#disable_or_delete_your_application

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue that you might have to contact [Google Apps Help Center](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en&ref_topic=2412034)
1-877-355-5787 or [email](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en#contact=1) to get it resolved.

Comment: What about those with free google apps account.  There is no way to contact support. And this is an error on their side. :(