# Unable to Remove (Deleted) App Engine Service from Google Admin Dashboard

Tags: google-app-engine

I recently deployed a Google App Engine app and then set up a custom URL for it from my Google Apps Admin dashboard. Everything ok until the app engine app was deleted (it is no longer listed on my developer console): I would now like to remove it from my admin dashboard to reclaim the custom URL for a different GAE app.

From the admin dashboard, I go into "App Engine Apps" and select the one I want to remove. If I click "delete" on the web address I would like to reclaim, I get "We are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later." (and this has been happening for days). If, instead, I try to delete the service altogether, when I click to confirm I receive "You do not have the permissions necessary to uninstall this application."

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403207/not-able-to-remove-google-app-engine-service-from-the-admin-console) question which suggests getting in touch with the Google Apps help center. After doing that, I received the following:

> Our Google Apps team offers support for the core suite of Google Apps services defined at http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/terms/user_features.html. The issue you’ve experienced is currently outside the scope of our support offering and we won’t be able to offer you further direct assistance at this time.

Does anyone know how I can remove the (deleted) app engine app from my admin console, to reclaim the custom URL?

Comment: I had a weird issue that looked like that.... I know it'll sound weird, but adding the URL on my App Engine console and verifying it there let me delete it from my Apps console.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, support said they couldn't help me and my posts were deleted from the board; I have no solution for you, but what I ended up doing is deleting the domain completely, setting it up again, the old app was still linked to it (had a mini-stroke) but still I made a new console project, bind the subdomain successfully, and then was able to delete the old reference for good. If you can solve it in any other way please let us know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from @Patrice's suggestion, I managed to resolve this from the app engine console (note: not the app admin console, where I was focusing all my efforts/receiving all those cryptic error messages).

I followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) to add a custom URL in the app engine console . After verifying my domain, I added my custom URL to my new app engine project. When I clicked to confirm, I got some warning saying that this custom URL is currently pointing to another app engine app and that by confirming, it would no longer point there.

I clicked confirm, and now everything is working.